# First n rows per group combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the first n rows for each group combination, for example

With the following input I would like to get the first two rows per product-area combination, ordered by date:

```
product  area  date        units
A        US    2015/08/07  10
A        US    2015/08/08  12
A        US    2015/08/09  15
A        UK    2015/08/07  13
A        UK    2015/08/10  11
B        US    2015/08/07  16
B        US    2015/08/08  17
B        US    2015/08/09  12
B        UK    2015/08/07  10
B        UK    2015/08/08  09
B        UK    2015/08/09  07
```

would return

```
product  area  date        units
A        US    2015/08/07  10
A        US    2015/08/08  12
A        UK    2015/08/07  13
A        UK    2015/08/10  11
B        US    2015/08/07  16
B        US    2015/08/08  17
B        UK    2015/08/07  10
B        UK    2015/08/08  09
```

I've tried:

```
with ordered as (select product, area, date, units, 
                            row_number() over (partition by product, area order by date asc) as date_rank
                            from mytable)
                            select product, area, date, units
                            from ordered 
                            where date_rank <= 2
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  And what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns the correct results. The only thing I see that could be missing from your query would be an `order by` for your final `select`:

```
with ordered as (
  select product, area, date, units
    , row_number() over (partition by product, area order by date asc) as date_rank
  from mytable
)
select product, area, date, units
from ordered 
where date_rank <= 2
order by product, area desc, date_rank
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XOMS68876

returns:

```
+---------+------+------------+-------+
| product | area |    date    | units |
+---------+------+------------+-------+
| A       | us   | 2015-08-07 |    10 |
| A       | us   | 2015-08-08 |    12 |
| A       | uk   | 2015-08-07 |    13 |
| A       | uk   | 2015-08-10 |    11 |
| B       | us   | 2015-08-07 |    16 |
| B       | us   | 2015-08-08 |    17 |
| B       | uk   | 2015-08-07 |    10 |
| B       | uk   | 2015-08-08 |     9 |
+---------+------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.product, t1.area, t2.date, t2.units
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.product, t1.area
    FROM mytable
) AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 2 date, units
    FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t1.product = t2.product and t1.area = t2.area
    ORDER BY date DESC
) AS t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ROW_NUMBER()**.

```
SELECT Product, Area, Date, Units
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, area ORDER By date ASC) AS xRowNumber FROM MyTable) xyz
        WHERE xRowNumber < 3
```